# Переход к другому файлу JS

Tags: javascript, файлы

UPD
Есть файл index.html и index2.html
Они оба лежат на хостинге, но в разных папках
Index.html лежит в корне, а index2.html лежит в папке Mikula. Как сделать переход из index.html в index2.html?

```
if (mouse.isPeekObject('LEFT', records)) {

        }
```

Сюда необходимо всунуть переход.

Comment: <a href="/Mikula/index2.html">Go</a> или в чём вопрос вообще?

Comment: Да, что то на подобии такого. А есть другие методы? Потому, что выдаёт ошибку на <> ковычки

Comment: Не могу понять, причём тут JS и где выдаёт ошибку, приведите фрагмент кода, где вы хотите получить желаемое поведение, иначе, я не смогу вам дать ответ точнее.

Comment: А как открыть ссылку таким же способом?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду, под открыть ссылку?

Comment: Ну предположим vk чей то

Comment: ну также, window.location.href="http://vk.com/id0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (mouse.isPeekObject('LEFT', records)) {
   window.location.href = "/Mikula/index2.html";
}
```